# Integrate $\ln(\left | \sin (x-y) \right |)$ over half period

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2 }\int_{0}^{\pi/2 } \ln(\left | \sin (x-y) \right |) dx dy$$

Edit 1:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2 }\int_{0}^{\pi/2 } \ln(\left | \sin (x-y) \right |) dx dy = \int_{0}^{\pi/2 }\int_{0}^{\pi/2 } (x)' \ln(\left | \sin (x-y) \right |) dx dy$$
$$ = \int_{0}^{\pi/2 }[(\pi/2)\ln(\left | \sin ((\pi/2)-y) \right |) -\int_{0}^{\pi/2 } x\cot(x)  dx ] dy$$

I tried this but that´s where I couldn't get further.

Comment: One limit is missing in the integral.

Comment: I apologise, I fixed it.

Comment: Use the fact that $(\log(\sin z))' =\cot z$ to your advantage with integration by parts. Also use symmetry to only evaluate the integral on either the upper or lower triangle after cutting the square in half by the line $y=x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using symmetry as suggested in the comments, the given integral is equal to $$I=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_y^{\pi/2}\ln\sin(x-y)~dx~dy=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2-y}\ln\sin z~dz~dy,$$ which, after changing the order of integration, becomes $$I=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2-z}\ln\sin z~dy~dz=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\pi-2z)\ln\sin z~dz.$$
This can be evaluated using $\int_0^\pi\ln 2\sin(x/2)\,dx=0$ and $\int_0^\pi x\ln 2\sin(x/2)\,dx=7$[$\zeta(3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant)$/4$ obtained, in turn, from the "Fourier" expansion $\ln 2\sin(x/2)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\cos nx)/n$ (with a little care). Finally, $$I=-\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln 2.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to calculate the last part without Fourier's Expansion, because we actually never do the "Fourier" part of calculus and I'm supposed to show it without Fourier's.

Comment: @variableXYZ: Not quite sure. Try searching for $\int_0^{\pi/2}x\ln\sin x\,dx$ (on this site, using [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)).